# get the values of a form field and save in database

Tags: php

I have a form in which i use two dimensional array for field names.The fields names are below

myform[message][]

myform[name][]

myform[add][]

it means there are three arrays.Every array has arrays inside it.when i var_dump my form after putting values and submitting it.I get the below structure of 2d array.

```
array
  ''message'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'adnan' (length=5)
      1 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      2 => string 'salman' (length=6)
  ''name'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      1 => string 'kamran' (length=6)
      2 => string 'khan' (length=4)
  ''add'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'asad' (length=4)
      1 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      2 => string 'abrar' (length=5)
```

As you can see the associative array.I want to store the values of message,name and add in a database table having three fields to store the values of message,name and add fields in a single query by using some loop like foreach.
when i use this code

```
foreach($_REQUEST['myform'] as $val)
 foreach($val as $v)

  {
    echo $v;
  }
```

I get all the values of the array.But i think i am unable to save it to database table

as all the values are in the variable $v.How to store message in a message field,name in name field and add in an add field in a table of a db.

please advice.Thanks

Comment: Release a larger portion of the code. Hard to understand the problem.

Comment: where is your approach? we are not here to give you full sort of code.

Comment: I can't actually understand what it is you're asking? Post what you've tried!

Comment: Even with your update, you don't explain how you want to store it in the database. What does your database look like that you want the data to go into, and do you want multiple values in for each answer or one row per value? You need to define the problem better if you want a better solution

Answer (score 2):

The looping is the easy part.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['myform']))
{
  foreach($_REQUEST['myform'] as $key=>$value)
  {
    // DO SOMETHING 
  }
}
```

The hard part is knowing what you want to do. You say put it in a database but you don't give any real info about what or where. Just make sure you carefully escape any user input before storing it, or better yet use prepared queries.